# How can I join adjacent lines based on whether their first field is empty?

Tags: sed, awk, text-parsing, reformat

Can I append a line to the previous one based on whether the first few characters are blank?

For example, I have data below:

```
zone:  z_ABCSVR01_STORAGE1
                ABCSVR; STORAGE1_P1;
        STORAGE_P2  
zone:  z_SUNSVR1_NBUSANCP
                SUNSVR1; NBUSANCP;
zone:  z_WINSVR01_STORAGE2
                WINSVR01; STORAGE1_P2;
        STORAGE_P3
```

And I need the output below:

```
z_ABCSVR01_STORAGE1 ABCSVR; STORAGE1_P1;    STORAGE_P2                      
z_SUNSVR1_NBUSANCP  SUNSVR1; NBUSANCP;               
z_WINSVR01_STORAGE2 WINSVR01; STORAGE1_P2;  STORAGE_P3
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way if you have `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='zone:' '$1=$1' file
z_ABCSVR01_STORAGE1 ABCSVR; STORAGE1_P1; STORAGE_P2
z_SUNSVR1_NBUSANCP SUNSVR1; NBUSANCP;
z_WINSVR01_STORAGE2 WINSVR01; STORAGE1_P2; STORAGE_P3
```

Comment: what's the usage for `NR>1`? `awk -v RS='zone:' '$1=$1' file` is fine

Comment: no, in my env (CYGWIN), I didn't see the blank line.

Comment: @BMW Is right, `{$1=$1}1` would print the blank line but `$1=$1` doesn't because this implicitly also evaluates `$1` in a boolean context like e.g. `$1{$1=$1;print}` (that's my understanding anyway).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks I didn't realize his comments did not include the braces. Fixed!

Comment: To explain this beauty: `RS='zone:'` breaks the input into records _across lines_, between occurrences of `zone:`. `$1=$1` triggers rebuilding of each input record based on `OFS` (the output field separator, a single space by default) - this is what merges the lines and (also folds multiple spaces into one); on output, records are separated by ORS, which defaults to `\n`. See @AdrianFrühwirth's comment for why - as desired - an empty line is NOT printed at the start, even though the input _starts_ with `zone:` (and the first record processed is therefore _empty_).

Comment: Also works with `mawk` (default `awk` version on Ubuntu and Debian, e.g.).

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk '{printf (/^zone/)?RS $0:FS $0}' file

zone:  z_ABCSVR01_STORAGE1                 ABCSVR; STORAGE1_P1;         STORAGE_P2
zone:  z_SUNSVR1_NBUSANCP                 SUNSVR1; NBUSANCP;
zone:  z_WINSVR01_STORAGE2                 WINSVR01; STORAGE1_P2;         STORAGE_P3
```

or

```
awk '{printf (/^[[:space:]]/)?FS $0:RS $0}' file
```

If you need remove useless white space:

```
awk '{printf (/^zone/)?RS $0:FS $0}' file|awk '$1=$1'

zone: z_ABCSVR01_STORAGE1 ABCSVR; STORAGE1_P1; STORAGE_P2
zone: z_SUNSVR1_NBUSANCP SUNSVR1; NBUSANCP;
zone: z_WINSVR01_STORAGE2 WINSVR01; STORAGE1_P2; STORAGE_P3
```

Comment: To remove white space do: `awk '{$1=$1;printf (/^zone/)?RS $0:FS $0}' file`

Comment: For keyword `/^zone/`, this command is fine. But if follow rule as `first few character are blank`, it can't

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x;s/\n  *//g;p;}' YourFile
```

removing also white space when line are joined

Answer (score 0):

If `GNU awk` is available, @jaypal's concise and elegant solution is the way to go.

Here's a **POSIX-compliant solution** that tries to dot the i's and cross the t's (what makes @jaypal's solution not compliant is the use of an `RS` (record separator) value that contains more than one (literal) character):

- It removes `zone:` from the output, as requested by the OP
- It doesn't print an extra `\n` at the beginning or omits a trailing one.
- It uses `printf` safely, with a format argument, to avoid accidental control char. expansion in input lines.

```
awk '{ 
      if ($1=="zone:") { sep=(notFirst++ ? ORS : ""); $1=""; $0=substr($0,2) } 
      else             { sep=OFS; $1=$1; }
      printf "%s%s", sep, $0
     }    
    END { print }
    ' file
```

Here's a heavily commented version of the same program that hopefully explains the more arcane features of `awk` used here:

```
awk '
  { 
    if ($1=="zone:") { # Zone lines            
        # Determine the separator to *precede* the output line:
        # ORS, the output *record* separator, which defaults to \n
        # - unless it is the very first line.
        # Net effect: zone lines start new output lines.
      sep=(notFirst++ ? ORS : ""); 
        # Remove the `zone:` field by setting the first field,
        # $1, to an empty string.
        # Note: This causes the entire line to be rebuilt by joining the
        #       fields with OFS, the output field separator, which defaults
        #       to a space. Multiple adjacent space chars. are folded into 
        #       one in the process.
      $1=""; 
        # Remove the space char. at the beginning of the rebuilt
        # line that stems from setting $1 to an empty string.
      $0=substr($0,2)
    } else {         # Non-zone lines
        # Determine the separator to *precede* the output line:
        # just the regular output *field* separator (space), 
        # effectively causing this line to be appended to the
        # previous one.
      sep=OFS;
        # Trigger rebuilding the line so as to fold 
        # multiple adjacent space chars. into one.
      $1=$1;
    }    
      # Output the separator followed by the rebuilt line.
    printf "%s%s", sep, $0
  }
    # Since the `printf` statement above never outputs
    # a *terminating* \n, we output one at the very end.
  END { print }
  ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nzone:/!s/\n\s*/ /;ta;s/^zone:\s*//;P;D' file
```